# FB like button doesn't work in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, facebook

I have a single page website, developed, that loads different pages (java-script+html) through ajax. I have included the FB like button in the footer section  which is common to all the pages. Now, the problem is whenever I navigate from one page to other, the like button doesn't show up until I refresh the entire page. E.g. initially, when HOME page is loaded the FB like button appears in footer. But when navigated to ABOUT page it doesn't show up. Now, when the ABOUT page is refreshed, the like button shows up. After this when I navigated back to the Home page, again the button disappears. Here's the code which I use to embed the button in my pages:

```
    //This is to be included in the html page at the start
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
       js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

    //Below html block is included where you want to place the FB like button
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/yourPage" 
         data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" 
         data-show-faces="true" data-send="true"></div>
```

Note that the pages (HOME and ABOUT) are loaded asynchronously on a single parent page.

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because facebook initializes itself only once and only when it initilizes itself, it will showup your FB Like Button.

So if you navigate to another site with AJAX (btw that's kinda bad for seo), facebook is still initialized and doesn't know to render your FB Like Button again. So only a reload will facebook initialize facebook JS again and then your FB Like Button shows up.

Comment: Thanks @jurik. How can i change my code so as to correct this? And is it bad to navigate from one page to another using AJAX? I use the backbone router for that i.e. while changing pages the url changes after the # tag. e.g. navigate from home (http://www.mysite.com/frontend#home) to about (http://www.mysite.com/frontend#about).